# Helm Chart upgrade in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm

I am setting a Azure CI-CD pipeline for microservice application. I have successfully containerized my application and pushed to azure container registry. I have packaged the helm chart in ci pipeline. Everything is running smoothly until it reaches helm upgrade.
In the release pipeline it fails at helm upgrade throwing the below error

[image]

In the release task , I have given helm configuration as follows:

```js
1.Connected to the Resource group and the Kubernetes Cluster in Azure
2.Selected the upgrade command
3.Selected the chart path where tgz file resides
4.In the set values , the below was given:
image.tag=$(Build.BuildID)
5.set the path to Values.yaml file
6.In the arguments section, gave the below:
--set web.image.tag=$(Build.BuildID) --set releasename='<appName>'
```

Please guide me where I went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try setting a `Release Name` in the Release Name section. And set the values in the `Set Values` section (`web.image.tag=$(Build.BuildID),releasename='<appName>'`) instead of in the `Arguments` section. See below screenshot.

[image]

To Specify the version of Helm. You can use [Helm installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/helm-installer?view=azure-devops).

[image]

Comment: this app name is the value that we pass in the deployment yaml file?

Comment: @Asterix Do you mean the release name is passed as a variable to the pipeline?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I confused release name with something else. sorry. yes now its fixing